# hyper v force merge .avhd

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v

I have a server running windows 2008 hyper v with 4 virtual machines on it. There was some raid controller issue and I've lost parts of the snapshots in the process due to corruption. I am wondering if there's a way I can force the remaining snapshots I saved to merge and form a semi/functional system to at least save some files? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. Restore from backup. That's your only option at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6257.manually-merge-avhd-to-vhd-in-hyper-v.aspx).

> To Start Merge follow the below steps
>
> 1. First Identify the Youngest AVHD ( In Our Ex : AVHD4)
> 2. Rename the Youngest AVHD (AVHD4)  to VHD
>
>    1. Should not rename all the AVHDs at a time. Need to Rename only Youngest Avhd
>         First
> 3. You can choose the Edit Disk option from the Actions menu in
>      the Hyper-V Management Console.
> 4. Click Next through the first screen and select the snapshot file on the following screen.
> 5. Select Merge on the next screen and choose the To parent virtual disk option and click
>      Finish.
> 6. After Successfully Completing Merge, Now Automatically AVHD4 will be deleted.
>
>    1. Now Rename the Second Youngest Avhd (AVHD3) to Vhd.
> 7. Repeats the Steps from 1 to 4 until Oldest AVHD ( AVHD1) Get Merge with Parent VHD.
> 8. Once this has completed you should create a new
>      virtual machine with the default options you would normally use,
>      selecting to use an existing virtual disk on the hard disk screen. You
>      should select the newly merged VHD file.